# RavenDB: how to retrieve the top nodes in a nested collection?

Tags: c#, collections, nested, ravendb

I stored the objects of the following classes in a ravendb database:

```
public class Continent
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Country> Countries{ get; set; }
    }

public class Countries
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Province> Provinces{ get; set; }
    }

public class Province
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Province> Cities { get; set; }
    }

public class City
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address   { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I retrieve from the database all the continents having cities with Name and Address respectively set to "aloma" and "123"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using the following query:

var continents = session.Query()
     .Where(c=>x.Countries.Any(country => country.Provinces.Any(p=>p.Cities.Any(city => city.Name == "123" && city.Address == "aloma"))).ToList();

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It helped me a lot. I modified it slightly to use it in my environment and it led me to a query similar to the following one: var continents = session.Query<Continent>() .Where(x=>x.Countries.Any(country => country.Provinces.Any(p=>p.Cities.Any(city => city.Name == "123" && city.Address == "aloma"))).OfType<Continent>().ToList();

Comment: I have another question related to the previous one. I am trying to retrieve all the continents having provinces whose cities include: 1) a city with Name and Address respectively set to "aloma" and "123" and 2) another city with Name and Address respectively set to "Hemane" and "435" . I've tried different things but I have not been successful so far.Can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need two Any() clauses for both cities.