# RavenDB: transforming a session.Query into a session.Advanced.DocumentQuery

Tags: c#, nested, ravendb

I stored the objects of the following classes in a ravendb database:

```
public class Continent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Country> Countries{ get; set; }
}

public class Countries
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Province> Provinces{ get; set; }
}

public class Province
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Province> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address   { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks to a post ([RavenDB: how to retrieve the top nodes in a nested collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295426/ravendb-how-to-retrieve-the-top-nodes-in-a-nested-collection/34310940?noredirect=1#comment56522853_34310940)) I have learned how to to use session.Query to retrieve from the database all the continents having cities with Name and Address respectively set to "aloma" and "123". I would like to write the same query using session.Advanced.DocumentQuery. So can you please tell me how to transform the following query into a session.Advanced.DocumentQuery:

```
var continents = session.Query<Continent>()
    .Where(x => x.Countries.Any(country => 
        country.Provinces.Any(p => 
            p.Cities.Any(city => 
                city.Name == "123" && city.Address == "aloma")))
    .OfType<Continent>()
    .ToList();
```

?

Comment: I finally used Fiddler to do that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418915/ravendb-use-fiddler-to-retrieve-the-structure-of-the-queries-sent-to-the-databa?noredirect=1#comment56580104_34418915)

Comment: But an answer is proposed on the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437364/ravendb-how-to-transform-a-session-query-into-a-session-advanced-documentquery