# RavenDB: how to transform a query into a lucene query?

Tags: c#, nested, ravendb, hierarchy

I have the following code:

```
public class Continent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Country> Countries{ get; set; }
}

public class Countries
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Province> Provinces{ get; set; }
}

public class Province
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Province> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address   { get; set; }
}
```

I want to transform the following query into a lucene query(e.g., Where, Any), so that I get the continents where both Aloma and Hemane are within the same province (and not in distinct provinces) with the respective addresses 123 and 435:

```
 var queryResults = from continent in session
                              .Advanced.DocumentQuery<Continent>()
                               from country in continent.Countries
                               from prov in country.Provinces
                               let cities_ = prov.Cities
                               let fi = cities_.Where(fp => fp.Name == "Aloma" && fp.Address == "123").FirstOrDefault()
                               let fj = cities_.Where(fk => fk.Name == "Hemane" && fk.Address == "435").FirstOrDefault()
                               where fi != null && fj != null
                               select continent;
```

I originally tried the following, but it returns results when Aloma and Hemane are in the same province (what I want), but also when Aloma and Hemane are in distinct provinces (what I don't want):

```
var queryResultsLucene = session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<Continent>()
                                 .Where("Countries,Provinces,Cities,Name:Aloma")
                                 .AndAlso()
                                 .Where("Countries,Provinces,Cities,Address:123")
                                 .Intersect()
                                  .Where("Countries,Provinces,Cities,Name:Hemane")
                                 .AndAlso()
                                 .Where("Countries,Provinces,Cities,Address:435")
                                 .OfType<Topic>()
                                 .ToList();
```

Can you please help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RavenDB, LINQ: how to transform a query into a lucene query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535914/ravendb-linq-how-to-transform-a-query-into-a-lucene-query)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Lucene query from my response on [RavenDB: how to transform a session.Query into a session.Advanced.DocumentQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437364/ravendb-how-to-transform-a-session-query-into-a-session-advanced-documentquery) . I wouldn't use this with a large number of cities though.

```
 var continentsToFindByCity = new List<City>(){new City{Name = "Aloma", Address = "123"}, new City{Name = "Hemane", Address = "435"}};
 var results = new List<Continent>();


    foreach(var city in continentsToFindByCity)
    {
        var tempResults = session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<Continent>().Where(
            string.Format("Countries,Provinces,Cities,Name: {0} AND Countries,Provinces,Cities,Address: {1}", city.Name, city.Address)).ToList();

        if(tempResults.Count > 0)
            results.AddRange(tempResults);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jared. It is really helpful. However, as clarified in my question, I want a query that returns me the list of continents if and only if Aloma and Hemane are both within the same Province. Your query is working when they are within the same  Province (what I want) but also when they are in distinct provinces (want I do not want). Can you please help me figure out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
var queryResults = session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<Continent>()
                    .OpenSubClause()
                        .WhereEquals("Countries,Provinces,Cities.Name", "Aloma")
                        .AndAlso()
                        .WhereEquals("Countries,Provinces,Cities.Address", "123")
                    .CloseSubClause()
                    .AndAlso()
                    .OpenSubClause()
                        .WhereEquals("Countries,Provinces,Cities.Name", "Hemane")
                        .AndAlso()
                        .WhereEquals("Countries,Provinces,Cities.Address", "Hemane")
                    .CloseSubClause()
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Ayende, your answer is really helpful. Thanks a lot for that. However, as clarified in my question, I want a query that returns me a list of continents if and only if Aloma and Hemane are both within the same Province. Your query is working when they are within the same Province  (what I want) but also when they are in distinct provinces (what I don't want). Can you please help me fix it?

Comment: Then you need to use Intersect, and have a query that output separate index entries per provice (fan out)