# RavenDB, Linq: Build an expression from a Property inside a nested hierarchy

Tags: linq, dynamic, nested, ravendb

I stored the objects of the following classes in a ravendb database:

```
 public class Continent
    {
       public string Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    }
    public class Country
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public List<Province> Provinces { get; set; }
    }

   public class Province
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
   }

   public class City
   {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Address { get; set; }
   }
```

I want to write a method that searches Continents having a specific city. The latter is a parameter of my method. In this method, I want to execute a dynamic query like the following: query= session.Query().Where(ConditionOnTheSearchedCity). But I can not formulate the Expression "ConditionOnTheSearchedCity" because I can not iterate till the Name of each City. In fact, to create an expression based on the Name of the City, I've tried the following which is not working:

```
  ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Continent), "p");

        Expression NameExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(
                                   Expression.PropertyOrField(
                                  Expression.PropertyOrField(
                             Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, "Countries"), "Provinces"),
                                  "Cities"),
                                   "Name");
```

Can you please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no direct answer because of the one-to-many relationships involved. You need to concretize your question.

Comment: I want to write a method that searches  Continents having a specific city. the latter is a parameter of my method. In this method, I want to execute a dynamic query like the following: query= session.Query<Continent>().Where(ConditionOnTheSearchedCity). But I can not formulate the Expression "ConditionOnTheSearchedCity" because I can not iterate till the Name of each City.

Comment: The problem is that you can only apply condition on `Continent`. There is no way to define condition on `City` w/o providing the whole criteria, i.e. `Any`, `All`, `Count` etc. Are you seeking for `Any` based filter like `session.Query<Continent>().Where(continent => continent.Countries.Any(country => country.Provinces.Any(province => province.Cities.Any(city => ConditionOnCity(city)))))`?

Comment: yes. I want to write the following request dynamically: session.Query<Continent>().Where(continent => continent.Countries.Any(country => country.Provinces.Any(province => province.Cities.Any(city => ConditionOnCity(city))))). In fact, I want to be able to generate dynamically all the content in the Where clause because the nature of my operations on the name of the city can change on the fly (e.g., equals, startWith). this can be done using expressions but I am not able to generate the right expression.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you going to all the trouble of dynamically building Linq?
Why not just use the RavenDB's `DocumentQuery` API which allows you to easily build queries dynamically?

Comment: I am using DocumentQuery to write dynamic queries. But I am stuck with queries such as the following that I can not translate into a Lucene Query:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444396/ravendb-how-to-transform-a-query-into-a-lucene-query

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, the question is too broad, so I'll give you just a starting point by providing an example. For more information, take a look at [How to: Use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx).

Let have a parameter `string cityName` and want a filter like this

```
Expression<Func<Continent, bool>> filter = continent => 
    continent.Countries.Any(country =>
        country.Provinces.Any(province => 
            province.Cities.Any(city => city.Name == cityName)));
```

It can be build dynamically like this

```
var city = Expression.Parameter(typeof(City), "city");
var cityCondition = Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(city, "Name"), Expression.Constant(cityName));
var province = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Province), "province");
var provinceCondition = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { city.Type },
    Expression.PropertyOrField(province, "Cities"),
    Expression.Lambda(cityCondition, city));
var country = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Country), "country");
var countryCondition = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { province.Type },
    Expression.PropertyOrField(country, "Provinces"),
    Expression.Lambda(provinceCondition, province));
var continent = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Continent), "continent");
var continentCondition = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { country.Type },
    Expression.PropertyOrField(continent, "Countries"),
    Expression.Lambda(countryCondition, country));
var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<Continent, bool>>(continentCondition, continent);
```